# How to set a DataGridView cell ForeColor property to red if the cell does not contain a value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to check that a cell on a `DataGridView` has a valid value. If it hasn't got a value I'd like to change the `ForeColor` property to red.

It's changing only the first row even if other rows haven't got any values.

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(autoMBS.dgvReceiverOut.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()) Then
    autoMBS.dgvReceiverOut.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
End If
```

Comment: Extremely annoying habit of programming languages. They do exactly what we tell them to do. :-) Your code only works with .CurrentRow

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's always recommended using [`DataGridView.CellFormatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) event that occurs when the contents of a cell need to be formatted for display.

You can check if `DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs` `e.Value` is valid: if not you have to change `e.CellStyle.ForeColor`.